# Two Accordions But Only Animating First Arrow Using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two accordions on my page. My script can target the first arrow to rotate it when it is clicked on but when I click on the arrow for the second accordion, the second accordion opens as expected but I can't figure out how to get the second arrow to rotate. Even when I click on the second accordion, the arrow for the first accordion rotates.

```
<a class="menu-accordion">
  @@include('img/icons/arrow-hcp.svg')
  text
</a>
<div class="panel">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/"> @@include('img/icons/chevron-right-wht.svg')</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<a class="menu-accordion">
  @@include('img/icons/arrow-hcp.svg')
</a>
<div class="panel">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/"> @@include('img/icons/chevron-right-wht.svg')</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>




  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-accordion");
  var svgarrow = document.querySelector(".menu-accordion > svg");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (panel.style.display === "block") { 
        panel.style.display = "none";
        svgarrow.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
      } 
      else {
        panel.style.display = "block";
        svgarrow.style.transform = "rotate(-90deg)";
      }
    });
  }
```